# if the base chage of all fibres of a morphism is faithfully flat, do we have flatness of the morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes over $S$ (with possibly Noetherian conditions all over the place).

For every point $s\in S$, the morphism base changed to the fiber $f_s:X_s\rightarrow Y_s$ is faithfully flat.

Do we have that $f$ is flat? or even faithfully flat?

Edit:  what if moreover both $X$ and $Y$ are flat over $S$?

Comment: If $Y=S$ and $f:X\to S$ is onto, then for every $s\in S, f_s:X_s\to s$ is faithfully flat since $s$ is the spectrum of the field. But $f$ is obviously not necessarily flat.

Comment: @Roland what if both of $X$ and $Y$ are flat over $S$? Then your example doesn't apply.